# XQuery that deletes few nodes

Tags: java, xml, xquery

I want to create a xq file (XQuery) which takes in a XML file that contains the following snippet, removes say 2 lines for "Ford, Harrison" & "Foster, Jodie" and then returns the remaining XML as is. How do I do that? Note: This xq file will be processed by a Java program.

```
<actors>
    <actor id="00000015">Anderson, Jeff</actor>
    <actor id="00000030">Bishop, Kevin</actor>
    <actor id="0000000f">Bonet, Lisa</actor>
    <actor id="00000024">Bowz, Eddie</actor>
    <actor id="0000002d">Curry, Tim</actor>
    <actor id="00000033">Dullea, Keir</actor>
    <actor id="00000042">Fisher, Carrie</actor>
    <actor id="00000006">Ford, Harrison</actor>
    <actor id="00000045">Foster, Jodie</actor>
...etc...
</actors>
```

Comment: is there a specific content you're loooking for in the line you want to delete?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably to rewrite the XML, and exclude the nodes you don't want.

```
let $exclude-names := ("Ford, Harrison", "Foster, Jodie")
return
  element actors {
  $xml-file/actors/actor[not(. = $exclude-names)]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile! How do I set $xml-file? Note: This is my first experience with XQuery.

Comment: @DilTeam It depends where the XML you used in your example is located.